# $f7router shows the correct "currentRoute" but $f7router.currentRoute shows previous route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, html-framework-7

I'm working on a tab view app with VueJS and Framework7.
I have `f7-links` that each open a `f7-view element` (so not actual tab elements). Inside one of these tabs, I would want to do nested navigation using `f7-link-item` with the `link` parameter. I am using the same component to render this page but I need to pass data to each link to identify which link was clicked (and to know which content to render).

I am trying to get this data with

```js
created() {
  console.log(this.$f7router.currentRoute);
}
```

But the weird thing is, this shows the previous route (the component that the link was clicked on, not the current component). If I do just

```js
created() {
  console.log(this.$f7router);
}
```

THEN the currentRoute shows the correct one.

For reference, my ordinary tab links are like this:

```html
<f7-toolbar tabbar labels bottom id="toolbar">
  <f7-link tab-link="#view-menu" tab-link-active text="Menu"></f7-link>
</f7-toolbar>
<f7-view id="view-menu" main tab tab-active url="/menu/"></f7-view>
```

And my nested routing links are like this:

```html
<f7-list-item link="/product/0" class="product-link">
  Coffee
</f7-list-item>
```

Routing itself works great, I just don't understand how to pass the prop I want and why the currentRoute parameter isn't working.

Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI, the reason you see a difference when logging `this.$f7router.currentRoute` vs `this.$f7router` is because chrome is not evaluating properties on `this.$f7router` until you expand them. Always log specific properties to avoid getting lazy evaluated results.

Comment: @Kordonme I didn't know this - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `this.$f7route` instead of `this.$f7router.currentRoute`.

> **$route or $f7route**
> *(object)*
>
> Current route. Contains object with route query, hash, params, path and url
>
> https://framework7.io/docs/router-component.html#component-context